# Why "just another bit of intrigue"?

Tags: vocabulary

The following is an excerpt from the transcript of a podcast:[Tut Shares Tomb with Former Fungi](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode.cfm?id=tut-shares-tomb-with-former-fungi-11-06-10).

> Mitchell thinks this evidence indicates that King Tut was buried in a hurry. Because the paint on the walls was probably still wet. And that moisture, along with the body and the food buried there, would have fed the wall fungus, until the tomb ultimately dried out. But why the hasty funeral? Just **another bit of intrigue** surrounding the boy king.

I am totally confused with the word "intrigue" here. When it is a noun, it means "a secret scheme". But what's the "scheme" supposed to be here? It seems that it's better to understand it as a verb--"If something, especially something strange, intrigues you, it interests you and you want to know more about it." But it is a noun here.

So here is my question:

> How to understand "*another bit of intrigue*" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bit of intrigue" can even be considered to be an idiom in English meaning a layer of mystery of secrecy. So this means that the hasty funeral is another mystery surrounding the boy king.

Answer (score 2):

It is meant in the sense of "something intriguing".  So an "intrigue" in this context is a mystery.